# How to use iTMSTransporter?

Tags: ios, xml, command-line

I have 50 achievements to upload to iTunes Connect. I have read that you can do this using iTMSTransporter however I cannot find references or examples of the script or metadata.xml file.

I have found the file here:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin`

Or here after updating to Application Loader 3.1:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin`

Can someone put up an example of the script and data structure needed to use it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can download metadata specifications and the `iTMSTransporter` manual
from iTunes Connect: https://itunesconnect.apple.com:

- Log in
- Click on *Manage Your App*
- See *Featured Resources* section for metadata guides
- See *Transporter* section for `iTMSTransporter` manual

You can also get help by executing `iTMSTransporter -help [command]`.

While I'm not familiar with uploading *achievements* I've written a Ruby gem that contains a small command line program that might help you:

https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter#readme

I also have a GUI (still somewhat rough around the edges) that might help: https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter_web/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter_web#readme

#### Update (2017-08-16)

Apple has created [iTunes Connect Resources & Help](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/overview).

- [Transporter User Guide](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/)
- [App Metadata Specification](http://help.apple.com/itc/appsspec/)

Film & TV specs are there too.

Comment: ppl keep showing that link and i login and and search the site for it and cant find it any chance you can deep link to the metadata section

Comment: iTunesConnect uses WebObjects, which apparently doesn't adhere to the basic tennets of the web. In other words any link I provide won't work. Log in and click on _Deliver_ _Your_ _Content_. The next page should have a _Featured_ _Resources_ section where you can download their specs. There should also be a _Transporter_ section where you can download the manual.

Comment: found it thx...can you update your answer with how to get to the doc like in you comments but rather than click Deliver your content can you put manage your app and i can mark this as answered.

Comment: Do you know is there a way to list all vendor_id?

Comment: @docchang This info is probably available in iTunes Connect. If you know a vendor ID you can lookup the statuses of previous uploads, but there's no way to list all your vendor IDs using Transporter (unless there is a new feature that I don't know about).

Comment: Great work on that ruby stuff. Please find me on twitter: http://twitter.com/docchang It would be cool to connect with you.

Comment: @docchang I don't use Twitter, but you can find my email somewhere in a GitHub repo...

Comment: cool! does this also somehow interact with the testflight part? (adding users, for example)

Comment: Is there an updated answer for this issue when using the newest version of iTunes Connect (2017). I don't explicitly see a `Manage Your App` or `Tools` section.

Comment: @KSigWyatt see my updated answer. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the update @sshaw. I was able to fix a related issue simply by re-installing Xcode altogether

Answer (score 9):

WWDC 2013 Session 306 *"What's New in iTunes Connect"* shows some examples of how to use `iTMSTransporter`. If you have access to an iOS Developer Program account, you should definitely check out this session.

For convencience, I added an alias to my `.bash_profile`. This allows me to invoke `iTMSTransporter` from any directory:

```
alias iTMSTransporter='`xcode-select --print-path`/../Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter'
```

Comment: ```/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter```

Comment: What's New in iTunes Connect - WWDC 2013 - Videos - Apple Developer:https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/306/

Answer (score 8):

use [altool](http://jaredverdi.com/post/101603121968/continuous-integration-and-apple-testflight) -- it works the same as iTMSTransporter, but a bit more concise.

It's found here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool
```

use as follows in a post-run jenkins script:

```
$ altool --upload-app -f /path/to/app.ipa -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

Comment: Got an issue with altool which locks the apple acount... as it outputs Password = **hidden value**, no idea which password is used...

Comment: I was having an old iTMSTransporter in my /usr/local that was giving this issue

Comment: however altool does require itmstransporter

Comment: use app specific pass: -> https://www.imore.com/how-generate-app-specific-passwords-iphone-ipad-mac

Answer (score 5):

Transporter User Guide

`export TRANSPORTER_HOME=xcode-select --print-path/../
Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin`

To start Transporter, use the iTMSTransporter command in the Terminal app. You must use 
the iTMSTransporter command in the directory where Transporter is installed. To use 
Transporter, you must have an iTunes Connect account with the Admin or Technical role.

**Using Lookup Mode**

`$ iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u [iTunes Connect user name] -p [iTunes Connect password] -vendor_id [App SKU] -destination [destination path for App Store Package]`

**Using Verify Mode**

`$ iTMSTransporter -m verify -f [path to App Store Package] -u [iTunes Connect user name] -p [iTunes Connect password]`

**Using Upload Mode**

`$ iTMSTransporter -m upload -f [path to App Store Package] -u [iTunes Connect user name] -p [iTunes Connect password]`

Comment: Can you help to understand what [destination path for App Store Package] value should be?

Comment: @dandepeched here's my working example:

`./iTMSTransporter -m upload -u "myAppleId" -p "myAppSpecificPW" -vendor_id "mySKU" -f ~/Documents/somename.itmsp`

I created a folder named `somename.itmsp` (or anything, just with the extension *.itmsp) in my Documents-directory and put a file `metadata.xml` and all needed screenshots inside.

Answer (score 0):

update iTMSTransporter update following links:-
https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA3ae5a8b0?sub=apdA687d545d

then check *App developer installation* step and download iTMSTransporter package
then install it.
I hope to resolve the error