# submit app with iTMSTransporter

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

Is it possible to submit a signed ipa file to the itunes connect with iTMSTransporter and skip the app upload from Application Loader or XCode?

Thanks!

Comment: Check commands may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17824838/905514

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, however not publicly documented by Apple. In the [deliver](https://fastlane.tools/deliver) tool, the following code allows you to upload an ipa file:

- [ipa_upload_package_builder.rb](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ipa_upload_package_builder.rb)
- [itunes_transporter.rb](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/itunes_transporter.rb)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The ITMSTransporter is only for uploading App Store packages (.itmsp) to the App Store. This means information about the application/game you're doing like

- Localization
- Territory
- In-App-Purchase
- Gamecenter

You still need to use the application loader or XCode for uploading the ipa.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I've yet to try it, but I'd say you can, even though in a very hacky way. Read this blog post about it:
http://diegopeinador.blogspot.se/2013/10/automatic-app-creation-and-binary-upload.html

Comment: I've tried the "upload with transport" part of that blog entry now, and it does infact work if iTunes Connect is in the "Waiting for upload" state.

Comment: No you can't. To this day, the blog post is wrong, the software_assets parts of the metadata can only be used for hosted in-app purchase packages. Not for an .ipa file.

Comment: Well, maybe you can't, but we can. With an .ipa file.

Comment: If it works, it is a 100% hack then and not officially supported by Apple (and I cannot change my down vote yet - the answer has to change before SO allow me to change my vote - but there is a huge difference between "i'd say you can" and "we can").

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's a hack, and it is definitely an undefined function that may change when ever, and not in any documentation from Apple. But still the person asking the question may still be interested that it's possible to do it this way... I'll add a note about it being undocumented feature in the reply if that's why you down voted it. I thought it was pretty clear from reading that blog post that it was a hack. =)

Comment: The down vote was not about the hacky part of it, it was more about the non very assertive way of mentioning the hack: "I've yet to try it, but I'd say you can" was not a proper answer to me but your comments made things clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I actually somewhat agree that I should assert it more clearly, as done now. Thank's for pointing that out, and for the up vote =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look on [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen/blob/0.14.2/lib/shenzhen/plugins/itunesconnect.rb#L28-L33)'s implementation, it's CLI tool used to upload ipa file to iTunesConnect