# how to adopt agile developmemt for iOS app while Apple take weeks to review it?

Tags: ios, agile

Good day!
As we know in agile development we need "quick feedback" to get incremental delivery. But in iOS development it is difficult due to the long time review process.

Each submit to appstore cost us one to two weeks to wait for our app to go live.
During that period we have to start our new iteration without any online feedback and then, 2 weeks later we have to pause our development to solve online issues once the review process passed.

In this case how can we adopt agile development practice ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: asked and answered at Programmers: [Should we quit trying to do agile if QA takes 12 weeks?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/96520/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No general rule that will fit all and solve all your problems, but here are some advices that will help:

1. Leverage iTunes Connect Testflight and your social channels to create an army of beta testers that can give you early feedback if something is terribly wrong
2. Dont stop development while your app is in a review, just continue working on whatever comes next and be ready to jump back to fix some issues
3. Prioritise app store feedback high
4. Don't be afraid to use expedited review feature, but again don't over use it as it will get us all in trouble.
5. Do user testing before actually developing features if possible
6. Automate testing as much as possible

These things among others will make your life easier, some of them are just best practices that can be applied in any other environment not just app store...

Comment: Thanks, kviksilver! Testflight is an option but I'm wondering how to automate the process for delivering my app to ituneconnect ONLY FOR TEST. 
Currently I have a version of 1.1 in review process and I would like to submit a version 1.2 to itunesconnect testflight for test. I tried to adopt shenzhen but it seems could only submit app to review directly. Till now I haven't found a way to submit to testflight automatically.

Comment: For nightlies we use crashlytics as a distribution and we run that on the build machine http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/370383-beta-distribution-with-ios-build-servers, once we have build ready for submission we publish it to testflight manually. Not sure if iTMSTransporter or altool will allow you to submit for beta app review, haven't tried it, but it looks like it should be capable... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582119/how-use-itmstransporter

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I think you should schedule a sprint only for "review issue" and start it only if there are some problem.
The review time it's about 4-5 days not 2 weeks I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use fabric to distribute my app to several beta users, make sure everything is tested as much as possible and then push application to appstore.

When you actually push your app you should be sure there will NOT be any major issues. As much as you test some small things might go by, but not major issues. Another key would be to have a team of testers that will test your app all the time.

Also, if your app is not working properly, you will get denied by Apple.

In the end, your fixes shouldn't take more then one day, or equivalent in story points.

Answer (score 0):

You can define external and internal testers while using TestFlight. Since uploading a build doesn't have a review process, then you can upload a new one every-week and your testers will receive a notification each time an update is available.